# I would like to get started with embedded device programming (if it's possible for someone like me)

Tags: c, embedded, device

I'd like to get into embedded device programming with c (you use c for these things right?)
I have absolutely no idea where to start and when I try to look it up it always seems like they think I already know things.

I have a semi solid understanding of c++ and c and I just need something to help get me started with embedded device programming.

Comment: It would help if you were more focused. What sort of device would you like to program? You can choose anything from a thermostat to a jumbo jet. If you have a goal then you'll find that you will get better answers.

Comment: This is "not a real question" -- but don't let the impending "close" scare you away ;-) If you are interested in just *device programming*, than the Linux (or BSD) kernels are places to play about (and very easy to get lost in!). If you're more of a micro-controller (which is also a great place to play with a very simple CPU/instruction set and no worry about cache, pages, etc ;-), I'd recommend picking up a developer board such as a [Rabbit 2000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbit_2000). A number of hackers also seem to play with the LEGO Mindstorm, which is great for interactions ;-)

Comment: Arduino is also a popular choice for getting started

Answer (score 3):

I dont know what your programming skill level is.  I have a few instruction set simulators that you can use to get comfortable programming at that level without having to buy anything or break/melt anything.  https://github.com/dwelch67  I also have a number of board/chip bring up examples for a number of microcontrollers.

C and Assembler are the dominant programming languages but many others have been tried and are in fact used.  At the end of the day a processor runs machine code and assembler is human readable form of that, so no matter how high or low the programming language it ends up at the assembler/machine code level.

The msp430 launchpad board is $4.30, and the stm32 value line discovery around $10.  I recommend the msp430 family for getting your feet wet, ARM processors are everywhere so there is value in learning them.  And the arduino which is a board type that normally uses an Atmel AVR processor is wildly popular in the hobby/homebrew/diy market.  sparkfun.com is a great place for these kinds of boards, there is a lilypad and some other kits they came out with this year that has the arduino like (supported by the arduino software tools/environment) avr based hardware with buzzers and leds and a number of things in the kit so you can learn to program them without having to get into buying and wiring up more hardware.  Later an arduino uno might be in order then shields to plug into that.  The armmite pro and leaflabs maple and fez panda and others are non-avr based (arm usually) boards that meet the arduino footprint (so shields can be plugged in) but may or may not make an attempt to be C level source code compatible.

if by embedded you meant perhaps embedded linux then that is significantly higher level than what I was talking about and you should look into running qemu, qemu-system-arm for example.  qemu being an emulator, linux capable hardware is usually a number of times more expensive than the boards above, the boards above are often in the $50 or less range, linux capable is often (but not always) above $200 or $250.  Now if you hold out another month or two, hopefully, the raspberry pi is coming and it may shake things up. Or like the olpc it might serve to simply show the world that there is a desire for a product that they had misread the demand for.  I would recommend sticking with qemu for a while, the bulk of the learning is software not hardware.  the hardware knowledge can wait.